# Problem in deploying my portfolio website in vercel

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, vercel

My code is running fine in local host with no errors and whenever I am trying to deploy my app in vercel it is showing this error I don't know what should I do to fix this problem.

[Vercel Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nlnc8.png)

My package.json file is here [package.json file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8b7rl.png)

please suggest something what should I do to prevent this error.

Comment: You probably can't update your node version on vercel so update your other packages to compatible versions

Comment: @mousetail https://vercel.com/changelog/node-js-version-now-customizable-in-the-project-settings

Comment: Still it's a really bad idea to use a node version with a known insecure version of SSL